# CakePHP 1.3: Setting up Routes for Plugins

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a plugin that generates the following address:

```
http://www.domain.com/paginas/paginas/view/about_us
```

How do I go about creating a route that makes the above page accessible thru:

```
http://www.domain.com/paginas/about_us
```

Thank you,

**SOLVED**: **Based on "cetver's" answer I was able to create a solution that worked for me**

```
Router::connect(
    '/paginas/*',
    array(
        'plugin' => 'paginas', 
        'controller' => 'paginas', 
        'action' => 'view'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::connect(
    '/paginas/:page_name',
     array(
         'plugin' => 'paginas', 
         'controller' => 'paginas',
         'action' => 'view'
     ),
     array('page_name' => '[\w]+')
);

/*
plugin.controller
public function view($page_name) {
    ...
*/
```

Comment: That was probably a little more complicated than what I would like to see. Based on that I was able to create a solution that worked for me. See update on my questions

Comment: Yes, but in your route request can take any data this may be cause of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this below mention URL.

http://anuragtrivediphp.blogspot.in/2011/09/remove-controller-name-from-url.html